# Windows 7 Setup HDMI output

Tags: windows-7, hdmi

I need to install Windows 7 on a device that has no native display only HDMI output (A laptop with display gone bad).

But when I boot into the Windows 7 setup it does not show up on the HDMI device.

Is there a way to install Windows 7 (or 8, 10) on such a device?

Comment: See if win+p will work after you boot into setup

Comment: Try to boot the laptop with a closed lid and the external display connected to the HDMI. Some laptops enable the external video output in such situation.

Comment: Did you try the VGA port?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a working Windows 7 computer, you could create an
unattended installation, and even include programs and drivers.
Drivers are not required if Windows 7 supports your hardware out-of-the-box.

The best tool to use for that is [NTLite](https://www.ntlite.com/).
Its freeware version might be enough, as it supports :

- Image conversion
- Basic component removal
- Host hardware checklist
- Integration
- Tweaks
- Unattended setup
- Post-Setup automation

Preparing the unattended installation is best done on a computer that is
reasonably similar to your own.

Answer (score 0):

If the display has gone bad due to a video card issue, you're out of luck, the video is integrated into the laptop, so when it goes, you need to replace the processor unit with integrated graphics. If the screen is just broken then you should be able to hook up through the hdmi to an exterior screen, (I have in the past). Do you get anything at all? A blinking light or can you boot into the dos when starting up to see if that will show ?

Comment: I am able to boot into Ubuntu live USB so the video card is probably fine.